# Cómo insertar registro SQL en la última posición conocida con condicionales

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Teniendo la siguiente creación de tabla en SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `empleados`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `activo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `departamento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `posicion` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Y la inserción

```
INSERT INTO `empleados`(
    `id`,
    `nombre`,
    `activo`,
    `departamento`,
    `posicion`
)
VALUES
('1', 'CARLOS', 'Y', 'CONTABILIDAD', '1'),
('2', 'ALBERTO', 'Y', 'CONTABILIDAD', '2'),
('3', 'LAURA', 'Y', 'CONTABILIDAD', '3'),
('4', 'DIANA', 'Y', 'CONTABILIDAD', '4'),
('5', 'JAIRO', 'Y', 'VENTAS', '1'),
('6', 'JAIME', 'Y', 'VENTAS', '2'),
('7', 'ANA', 'Y', 'VENTAS', '3'),
('8', 'MARIA', 'Y', 'VENTAS', '4'),
('9', 'LUIS', 'Y', 'VENTAS', '5'),
('10', 'ANA', 'N', 'VENTAS', '6')
```

[image: EJEMPLO TABLA]

Necesito hacer un INSERT en el departamento CONTABILIDAD, para ello la siguiente posición debería ser **5**, pero si hago lo mismo en el departamento VENTAS, la posición debería ser **6** (Nótese que ya existe pero el estado es N, por lo tanto el valor más alto en VENTAS, es **5**).

Mi consulta select sería tal que así:

```
SELECT
    MAX(posicion)
FROM
    empleados
WHERE
    activo = 'Y' AND departamento = 'VENTAS';
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
INSERT INTO `empleados`(    
    `nombre`,
    `activo`,
    `departamento`,
    `posicion`
)
VALUES(
    'PEDRO',
    'Y',
    'VENTAS',    
    (SELECT MAX(posicion) + 1 FROM empleados WHERE activo = 'Y' AND departamento = 'VENTAS')
)
```

Pero obtengo el error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'empleados' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Para que usas el campo posición?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba insertando directamente el registro como resultado de una consulta, en vez de que el resultado de la consulta sea para un campo específico. Es lo mismo, pero no es lo mismo:

```
INSERT INTO empleados
SELECT
    NULL,
    'PEDRO',
    'Y',
    'VENTAS',  
    MAX(posicion)+1
FROM
    empleados
WHERE
    activo = 'Y' AND departamento = 'VENTAS';
```

Puedes comprobarlo en este fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/EsrxEdWc